# SQL procedure select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to write a procedure to database which will return select all data from database `Tournaments` plus bool parameter. If user is registered, it will return `true`.

Call:

```
exec TournamentsWithLoggedUser @user = 'asd123'
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TournamentsWithLoggedUser]
    @user  nvarchar(128)
AS
    SELECT 
        t.Id, t.Info, BIT(r.Id) 
    FROM  
        Tournaments AS t
    LEFT JOIN 
        Registrations AS r ON  t.Id = r.TournamentId
    WHERE
        r.UserId IS NULL OR r.UserId = @user

    RETURN
```

it mean something like

```
1, 'some info', true //1
2, 'some info2', false //2
```

Comment: I assume that it is possible somehow with IF EXIST but I am not able to figure out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this query

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.info, 
       Cast (CASE 
               WHEN r.userid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END AS BIT) AS IsRegistered 
FROM   tournaments AS t 
       LEFT JOIN registrations AS r 
              ON t.id = r.tournamentid 
                 AND r.userid = @user
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a case statement?

```
CASE WHEN r.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Change the 0 and 1 to whatever you want for false and true.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Info, 
    -- this works in SQL Server
    CAST ((CASE WHEN r.UserId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS IsRegistered 
FROM Tournaments as t
   LEFT JOIN Registrations as r ON t.Id = r.TournamentId
where (r.UserId = '' OR r.UserId = @user)
```

-- i think this one is help for you...

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify what SQL language you are actually using, but an answer can be provided anyway:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TournamentsWithLoggedUser]
    @user nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT t.Id, t.Info, 
        -- this works in SQL Server
        CAST ((CASE WHEN r.UserId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT) AS IsRegistered 
    FROM Tournaments as t
       LEFT JOIN Registrations as r ON t.Id = r.TournamentId
    where r.UserId IS NULL OR r.UserId = @user

    -- this should not be required
    RETURN
```

END

However, there is a problem with the logic:

`@user` is not nullable, so your procedure gives the impression that it looks data for a single user. However, your OR operator allows to select all records from unregistered users united with the record for the particular provided user (if exists).

Comment: Parameters in (regular) stored procedures are NULLABLE. You cannot declare them as `NOT NULL`, except for SQL Server 2014+ in natively compiled stored procedures specifying `WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION`. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx). Your statement *`@user` is not nullable* is false.